# The repeatUtil() not work on Rxjava 2.x

Tags: android, rx-java2

When I use the following code:(Observable.create())

```
    Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<User>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<User> emitter) throws Exception {
            emitter.onNext(new User("Even201314", 14));
        }
    }).repeatUntil(new BooleanSupplier() {
        @Override
        public boolean getAsBoolean() throws Exception {
            repeatCount += 1;
            Log.d(TAG, "count: " + repeatCount);
            return repeatCount > 10;
        }
    })
```

the method repeatUntil would not be executed.The console would not log anything.
But if I use the following code:(Observable.just())

```
    final User user = new User("Even201314", 24);
    Observable.just(user).repeatUntil(new BooleanSupplier() {
        @Override
        public boolean getAsBoolean() throws Exception {
            repeatCount += 1;
            Log.d(TAG, "count: " + repeatCount);
            return repeatCount > 10;
        }
    })
```

the method repeatUntil would be executed.And the console would log:

```
11-14 00:00:36.312 5788-5854/com.even.learningrxjava2 D/MainActivity: count: 1
11-14 00:00:36.312 5788-5854/com.even.learningrxjava2 D/MainActivity: count: 2
11-14 00:00:36.313 5788-5854/com.even.learningrxjava2 D/MainActivity: count: 3
11-14 00:00:36.313 5788-5854/com.even.learningrxjava2 D/MainActivity: count: 4
11-14 00:00:36.313 5788-5854/com.even.learningrxjava2 D/MainActivity: count: 5
...
```

I don't know why Observable.create() would not execute repeatUntil() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It need an `emitter.onComplete()` otherwise the repeat won't get triggered.